# Defining union types for multiple use parameters

Tags: typescript

I am making a fairly dynamic library and I am running into issues with defining union types in Typescript, here is an example function:

```typescript
var forArray = function (scope : SampleClass, ary : Array<any>|Function, fn? : Array<any>|Function) {
    fn = fn === undefined && scope.isFn(ary)
        ? ary
        : fn;
    ary = (scope.isFn(ary)) ? scope.clone(scope.src) : ary;

    for (var i = 0, l = ary.length; i < l; i++) {
        fn(ary[i], i, s);
    }
};
```

What I am trying to do is make a function that is dynamic in it's usage but I am getting the following error during compilation:

**Error 1:**

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.

I fully understand the error, `fn` can essentially be a Array due to this line:

```
fn = fn === undefined && scope.isFn(ary)
    ? ary // Since this is type Array<any>|Function
    : fn;
```

---

If I change `fn` type to be just `fn? : Function` or `fn? : (a, b, c) => any`, I get the obvious error:

**Error: 2**

> Type 'any[] | Function' is not assignable to type 'Function'.
>
> > **or**
>
> Type 'any[] | Function' is not assignable to type '(a: any, b: any, c: any) => any'.

So, is there a way to use union types in an end user forgiving manner that doesn't throw compilation errors, especially when using callback functions? Am I missing something?

And yes I know, if I were to use type `any` (or no type at all) I wouldn't get any errors etc, but I hate using `any` unless I am really looking for anything, I feel like I am abusing the system at that point.

---

**Disclaimer**, although `Error 1` above is thrown, it doesn't not prevent compilation and thus the code does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve with casting, I didn't realize that typescript had type casting:

```
var forArray = function (scope : SampleClass, ary : Array<any>|Function, fn? : Function) {
    fn = fn === undefined && scope.isFn(ary)
        ? <Function> ary
        : fn;
    ary = (scope.isFn(ary)) ? scope.clone(scope.src) : ary;

    for (var i = 0, l = ary.length; i < l; i++) {
        fn(ary[i], i, s);
    }
};
```

I changed `fn? : Array<any>|Function` to `fn?: Function`, so I now have strict type set on the callback. And then I added casting `<Function>` to the `ary` in the fn definition.

```
fn = fn === undefined && scope.isFn(ary)
    ? <Function> ary
    : fn;
```

All unit tests have passed and don't have any compilation errors.

Comment: You can go one step further and replace `Function` with `((a, b, c) => any)`. Also `ary as ((a, b, c) => any)` casting looks nicer to me :)

Comment: @mate agreed, I just wanted to show the more simplistic syntax for the answer. :)

Comment: @mate I didn't know about the `ary as` so thank you for that!

Comment: nit: its called *assertion* because casting implies runtime support : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't like those union types. You can check [an example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=type%20NameOrNameArray%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20string[]%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20createName%28name%3A%20NameOrNameArray%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20%28typeof%20name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22string%22%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20name.join%28%22%20%22%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20greetingMessage%20%3D%20%60Greetings%2C%20%24%7BcreateName%28[%22Sam%22%2C%20%22Smith%22]%29%20%7D%60%3B%0D%0Aalert%28greetingMessage%29%3B) on TypeScript homepage. Unless you're sure about type, you cannot use functions from this type. Just paste `return name.join(" ");` somewhere out the if-else statement in the provided example.